# From a vector to a shorter vector of averages in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

Let I have a vector `x` in Matlab of size 1000. I want to produce a vector `y` of length 10 where each component contains the average of 100 records from the vector `x`.

My attempt is quite simple

```
for i=1:10
 y(i) = mean(x((1:100)+(i-1)*100));
end
```

I wonder if there is a build in command or more elegant solution for this.

Comment: Hmmmm,... The Grammar Nitpicker can't help pointing out that the missing article is critical here :-) .  "each component contains **the** average of 100 records" is the intended meaning, but "each component contains **an** average..." can easily be interpreted as splitting the input into 10 records whose length is such that the mean record length is 100 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `reshape`-function to generate a 2d-array and then calculate the mean over the correct dimension.

This works as replacement for your loop:

```
y = mean(reshape(x,[100,10]),1);
```

*Note: It does not matter if `x` is a column-vector or a row-vector.*